# Execute p:commandLink action before onclick event?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:commandLink` which launches a dialog on click. Further there is an action, which must be executed *before* launching the dialog, as the dialog depends on the content the action populates.

How can I run the action before launching the popup *without* javascript?

```
<p:commandLink action="#{service.computePrefetch(_var)}" onclick="dlg.show()"/>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the oncomplete attribute and the ajax update attribute.

```
<p:commandLink action="#{service.computePrefetch(_var)}" update="dlgId" oncomplete="dlg.show()"/>
```

**Execution order:**

onclick->action->update->oncomplete

BalusC posted a detailed sequence [Execution order of events when pressing PrimeFaces p:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146630/primefaces-actionlistener-and-oncomplete-are-not-working-simultaneously)

Comment: its not working in my case 
here is my code 
<h:commandLink  title="File" action="#{service.fetchDetail(row.sNo)}"
         update="DlgId"
         oncomplete="PF('Dlg').show()" />