# RichFaces a4j:commandButton oncomplete

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Hi i have this demo form with RF 4.5.2, the oncomplete execute 3 times, i need a way to execute a method after the ajax call but only one time, i think that is the behaviour of the oncomplete but if it doesnt you can suggest any other ideas to accomplish this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body>
    <rich:panel>
    <h:form>
        <a4j:commandButton  id="btnAccion" value="enviar" oncomplete="#{archivoAfipController.emptyAction()}"/>
    </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: what does the `enter code here` do in your code ?! 
On the other hand, oncomplete must be a javascript function and not a method expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to use the `action` attribute for the purpose of invoking a managed bean method on submit.

```
<a4j:commandButton ... action="#{archivoAfipController.emptyAction}" />
```

The `oncomplete` must represent a client side script expression (thus, e.g. JavaScript, which is in JSF perspective basically a plain vanilla `String`!), which should be executed when the ajax action has completed, the response has returned, and all necessary parts of the view have been updated in the client side.

#### See also:

- [`<a4j:commandButton>` tag documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest/vdldoc/a4j/commandButton.html)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146879/ (only second half of the answer is relevant)