# Update part of the jsf page using primefaces update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, materialize

i have a dropdown-content(materialize css) and each of its row has button.  when i click button i want to change/delete one li of dropdown-content using primefaces update=""(Note, the dropdown-content must not be closed). 
BUT, i do not see any changes after click, AT THE SAME TIME, response from the server is right.
Why dropdown-content does not redraw?
This is my code:

```
  <h:form id="form" style="display: inline-block; height: 100%;">
                            <a href="#" id="dropButton"
                               class=" dropdown-button #{userContext.notificationsList.hasNewNotifications() ?'':'tooltipped'}"
                               data-tooltip="У Вас нет новых сообщений."
                               data-activates='messagesDropDown' data-constrainwidth="false" data-beloworigin="true"
                               data-gutter="20" style="height:100%">
                                <div>
                                    <p:outputLabel id="NotificationLabel">
                                        <i class="material-icons white-text">#{userContext.notificationsList.hasNewNotifications()?'notifications':'notifications_none'}</i>
                                        <span id="messageNumber"
                                              style="visibility: #{userContext.notificationsList.hasNewNotifications() ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}"
                                              class="active-badge">#{userContext.notificationsList.newMessageCount}</span>
                                    </p:outputLabel>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div>
                                <p:outputLabel id="listMessage">
                                    <ul id="messagesDropDown" class="dropdown-content " style="width:20%; ">
                                        <ui:repeat id="allMessagaes" class="collection"
                                                   value="#{userContext.notificationsList.notificationList}"
                                                   var="message">
                                            <p:panel id="panelWrapper">
                                                <li id="oneMessage" class="collection-item truncate"
                                                    onclick="event.stopPropagation()"
                                                    style="background-color: #{message.read ? '#fafafa' : '#e0e0e0' }; border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="left "
                                                             style="padding: 10px; width:85%;white-space:normal; word-wrap: normal ">#{message}</div>
                                                        <div class="right">
                                                            <p:commandLink style="padding: 0"
                                                                           actionListener="#{message.setRead(true)}"
                                                                           oncomplete="reloadComponents(); "
                                                                           update="@form:listMessage, @form:NotificationLabel"
                                                            ><i
                                                                    class="material-icons blue-text"
                                                                    style="font-size: 20px">done_all</i></p:commandLink>
                                                            <p:commandLink style="padding: 0"
                                                                           actionListener="#{userContext.notificationsList.removeNotification(message)}"
                                                                           oncomplete="reloadComponents()"
                                                                           update="@form:listMessage, @form:NotificationLabel"><i
                                                                    class="material-icons blue-text"
                                                                    style="font-size: 20px">close</i>
                                                            </p:commandLink>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </p:panel>
                                        </ui:repeat>
                                    </ul>
                                </p:outputLabel>
                            </div>
                        </h:form>
```

Comment: @Pechenka: The update is executed before the oncomplete. Take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146630/execution-order-of-events-when-pressing-primefaces-pcommandbutton