# How to call js function after ajax update finished

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have an ajax commandButton, when i clicked it, it updates the form that i used and call an js function on onclick method.

The problem : a field is invisible at first, i use `style="display:none"` forinvisibilty. When i click the button, it updates the form data and display:none is still there. On onclick command i use a js function to change the `style="display:none` to `style="display:block"`.

here is my js function :

```
setTimeout(function() {
PF('field').jq.css('display', 'block');
}, delay);
```

I use delay to wait the update finish its job.

here is my command button :

```
<p:commandButton ajax="true" update="form" onclick="jsFunc();"</p:commandButton>
```

But i want to be sure when ajax update finish its job, then i want to call the js function.

What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `onclick` for `oncomplete`, the oncomplete event is fire after the update, for more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146879/5527433)

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by success method !!
example :

```
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xxx.php",
            data: {
                'name': data
            },
            success: function(resp) { // resp is the response of php file !
            // something to do after ajax completed !!
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: what do u mean by PrimeFaces Button ??

Comment: `p:commandButton` is a PrimeFaces component. Ajax is not used this way in PrimeFaces or even JSF. See also http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/basic.xhtml

Comment: It's not applicable to pimefaces and JSF