# jsf doesn't use updated value in oncomplete method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i'm studting jsf, i have some problem using `<p:commandButton>` and `<f:actionListener>`.

I was testing my understanding of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146630/execution-order-of-events-when-pressing-primefaces-pcommandbutton)

so in a jsf page i wrote:

```
<p:commandLink  value="Test"
                onstart="alert(#{testBean.sayHello})"
                update="@this" //this should be redundant
                oncomplete="alert(#{testBean.sayHello})">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{testBean.setString()}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

the TestBean

```
@Named
public class TestBean {
    private String sayHello;

    public String getSayHello() {
        return sayHello;
    }

    public void setSayHello(String sayHello) {
        this.sayHello = sayHello;
    }

    public void setString(){
        setSayHello("Hello my friend");
    }
}
```

the first alert show just an empty string, but the second too, why?

Comment: Which question where is the link?

Comment: clic on "this question", the link is tagged