# p:commandButton doesn't dislpay p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a problem with the display of a dialog on a  click. It's a  obvious one but i can't spot the bug. I've been stuck on this for days, it's crazy. Can you help me please.

```
<h:form id="form">

<p:commandButton
    rendered="#{characterBean.characterSession.characterName ne null}"
    value="#{characterBean.characterSession.title.titleName}"
    icon="fa fa-fw fa-edit" onclick="PF('dlg').show();"
    update="@form"/>

<p:dialog id="titleDetail" header="#{i18n['title.yourTitles']}"
    widgetVar="dlg" dynamic="true" closable="false" resizable="false"
    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="titleSelect" converter="#{titleConverter}"
            value="#{characterBean.characterSession.title}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{characterBean.titleUnlocked}" var="t"
                itemValue="#{t}" itemLabel="#{t.titleName}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <hr />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%; text-align:center">
            <p:commandButton value="#{i18n['general.submit']}"
                icon="fa fa-check"
                actionListener="#{characterBean.updateCharacterTitle}"
                oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide();" update="@form" />

            <p:commandButton value="#{i18n['general.cancel']}"
                icon="fa fa-close" action="#{characterBean.submitCancel}"
                oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide();" update="@form" process="@this" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:remoteCommand name="updateForm()" process="@this" update="@form" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Sort of contradictiory... it is obivous but you can't spot it... Analyze what your code does. You have a dialog in a form and the dialog is initially hidden. You click the button which shows the dialog but at the same time you update the form to a state were... correct, the dialog is initally hidden. You knowhere keep the dialog state server  side. So the client-side action on it will get lost.

Comment: Thanks you both for your answer. It works :-). And thanks for the great explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core problem is essentially this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton onclick="PF('dlg').show();" update="@form"/>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg">
        ...
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

- The default state of `<p:dialog>` is hidden.
- The `onclick` shows the dialog.
- The `update` updates the entire content of the `<h:form>`.
- The `<p:dialog>` is also included in the update.
- So, the `<p:dialog>` gets hidden again.

There are several solutions:

1. Don't let `update` include the `<p:dialog>`.

   ```
   <h:form>
       <h:panelGroup id="outsideDialog">
           <p:commandButton onclick="PF('dlg').show();" update="outsideDialog"/>
       </h:panelGroup>

       <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg">
           ...
       </p:dialog>
   </h:form>
   ```
2. Replace `onclick` by `oncomplete` as it runs *after* the `update`.

   ```
   <h:form>
       <p:commandButton update="@form" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show();" />

       <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg">
           ...
       </p:dialog>
   </h:form>
   ```
3. Move `<p:dialog>` outside the `<h:form>` and give it its own `<h:form>`.

   ```
   <h:form>
       <p:commandButton update="@form :dlg" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show();" />
   </h:form>

   <p:dialog id="dlg" widgetVar="dlg">
       <h:form>
           ...
       </h:form>
   </p:dialog>
   ```

   or, depending on whether you actually need to update the dialog's contents or not

   ```
   <h:form>
       <p:commandButton onclick="PF('dlg').show();" update="@form" />
   </h:form>

   <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg">
       <h:form>
           ...
       </h:form>
   </p:dialog>
   ```

The recommended solution is 3.

#### See also:

- [Execution order of events when pressing PrimeFaces p:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146630/execution-order-of-events-when-pressing-primefaces-pcommandbutton/)
- [How to use <h:form> in JSF page? Single form? Multiple forms? Nested forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371903/how-to-use-hform-in-jsf-page-single-form-multiple-forms-nested-forms)
- [p:commandbutton action doesn't work inside p:dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958729/pcommandbutton-action-doesnt-work-inside-pdialog/)

Comment: Thanks you both for your answer. It works :-). And thanks for the great explanation.